# in vimscript how to write the code a CTRL-C to be executed

Tags: vimscript, global-command, control-character

I run a sourced vimscript like this:

```
exec 'g#' . WE_var_searchmode . ' ' . WE_var_pattertosearch . '#exec " A | B | C | make_CTRL-C | ... | LAST " '
```

The outer `execute '...'` is needed to pass variables as patterns.
The inner `execute " ... "` is needed so that the global command repeatedly executes some code.

On some condition, the repetition by `:global` is to be broken, like breaking a while loop. The help states that for `:global` only `CTRL-C` interrupts. Thus typing `CTRL-C` does work. But how can I write code in the script to interrupt?

I have not found a way; all my trials to produce `CTRL-C` result in error messages.

Comment: You might not need the inner execute if `A | B | C …` are not built out of variables/strings. I would try `:execute "normal! \<C-c>"` or `:call feedkeys("\<C-c>")`.

Comment: I've noticed you ask a few questions with similar content. I've [edit]ed them in the hopes that they will be more likely to attract answers with readable content, but the best way to get an answer is to be specific. Find a small example that demonstrates your issue. It's also possible we can suggest alternate ways to go about solving your problem which may help eliminate the need for some of the complexity you seem to be dealing with.